# Form is not styled at all in Internet Explorer - CSS doesn't show up

Tags: css, internet-explorer, forms

I'm at a major loss and really could use any sort of help!  I am writing a simple form on what will be a contact page (http://the4amburrito.com/contact.html)

The form is styled and looks fine in Safari and Firefox, but then in Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8... nothing!The strange thing is that the header is still styled in IE, which means the CSS must be loading.

I've validated the CSS and tried about a million different things but nothing works. I am teaching myself CSS so perhaps I've done something really silly that will be obvious to someone else? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Your HTML is broken. For example, here's a missing `>`:

```
    <div id="contact"
    <form action="send_message.php" method="POST">
```

Please make sure your HTML is valid (use http://validator.w3.org, for example), then try again.

Comment: yeah, need to validate your markup ... FF & Safari are pretty good at correcting it, so it displays properly when viewed in that browser.

IE though, for once, does the proper thing and alerts you to the problem.

Comment: Wow that was quite simple, my face is a little red. Thank you  for the super quick reply! When you are a beginner like me it is easy to become so frustrated that you forget to look for the most obvious errors. Once I got it validated the CSS on the form did show up. 

It seems ok (except for the ugly scroll bar in IE 7 & 8 in the message area) but in IE6 it is completely out of wack. 

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an IE6 lying around anymore. I don't know if this is an option in your situation, but in general I follow the principle "make sure it looks nice in IE>=7, FF, and all other standard-obedient browsers; then make sure it's *somehow* usable in IE6, even if it looks ugly". The problem is that "making it look good in IE6" too often involves throwing away all the nice div, css, ... stuff and rewriting it "the old way"...

Comment: I'm basing this off of looking at screen shots from Adobe Browserlab (https://browserlab.adobe.com/), and it appears as if in IE6 the side form is all the way down the page rather than to the right of the other box. 

I was just reading about the IE7  JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser... is that helpful at all or just an easy way out that doesn't really fix anything? 

Thanks again SO much for your help. I'm so happy I've stumbled across this great community.

Comment: The IE7 library might be worth a try; I've already successfully used it on one of my web pages for "minimal effort IE6 compatibility". (If it's ok for you that users with IE6 and JavaScript turned off still see the "ugly" version.)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your HTML code is broken.

The `div` tag before the `form` tag is missing the ending `>`.